# Dialogic D/41EPCI with .NET and C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have a tab called "Dialogic d/41epci" and I wanted to know if I can develop applications using Visual Basic.NET or C # (C # better). Is there any library or some SDK to use for this card?
If I can not develop with C # or VisualBasic What do you recommend?

Apologize me for my bad english i hope everyone understand me.

Thanks beforehand for your answers

EDIT: the topic is also for Visual c++

Comment: http://www.voice-boards.com/datasheet/d41epci.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are looking for a .NET Telephony API, in which case have a look at [ATAPI - Managed TAPI wrapper for TAPI 2.0](http://atapi.codeplex.com/) and its resource site [Microsoft Telephony API (TAPI)](http://www.julmar.com/tapi/).

Comment: Are you certain that's not simply a driver issue?

Comment: Yes because it work with sample program written in c and c++ .. i think i must developing stuff for d/41 in c++ damn :(

Comment: Check out this link (first one when Googling Dialogic and VB.Net):  http://www.dialogic.com/products/docs/appnotes/11170-dalogic-apis-net-apps-an.pdf